# scaling objects depending on instancer number (animation nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

How i can scale objects depending on number? attached a picture for clarity
[image]

Answer (score 4):

A full procedural and vectorized approach would be as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

The cosine and sine are simply the parametric equation of the circle which is periodic, if we scale it based on its parameter, we get the spiral effect, the scale of the objects can be defined as a scalar multiple of the parameter as well.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a simple array modifier, but yes, it's a bit fiddly to bet all the numbers right.

[image: AN Scale By Index]

This way does it by invoking a Loop SubProgram.

Comment: You don't have to use a loop for this. All of those nodes are vectorized, so you can get the equivalent of an index through the *Integer Range* or the *Float Range* nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Select all spheres,
Open the python console & type:

```
a = 0.1
for i in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    i.scale = (a, a, a)
    a = a + 0.1
```

You have to do the math according to you number of objects and the size you want to scale them by to set up the initial value and increase of a.

Comment: The question is about Animation Nodes and not a general question about how to achieve the effect.